# Using d3 drag, why doesn't dragstart have d3.event.x set?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can access `d3.event.x` from inside `on("drag"...)` but `x` doesn't exist inside `on("dragstart"...)`; why? And how can I get it another way, preferably not very hackish?

Check console output for this example:

```
d3.select("body").append("svg").append("rect")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("color", "black")
    .call(
        d3.behavior.drag()
            .on("dragstart", function(){
                console.log(d3.event);
            })
            .on("drag", function(){
                console.log(d3.event);
            })
            .on("dragend", function(){
                console.log(d3.event);
            })
        );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntfqgmag/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lars explains why, so how do you do it?  [d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse) is pretty slick:

```
    d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", function(){
            console.log('relative to rect: ' + d3.mouse(this));
            console.log('relative to body: ' + d3.mouse(d3.select("body").node()));
        })
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ntfqgmag/3/).

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#on)):

> Drag events (but not dragstart and dragend events) expose "x" and "y" properties representing the current position of the drag gesture in local coordinates.

The start and end events are fired before and after the actual drag takes place, i.e. there's no coordinate change compared to the first and last `drag` events.